# imp.load_source loads wrong module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have two supposedly identical systems. On both systems, I run the same software, but on one of the two it doesn't function correctly.

I'm trying to run function in a user-supplied `.py` file. I've reduced this to the following basic code that reproduces the error:

```
import imp
with open("test_scripts/load_offsets.py") as fp:
    module = imp.load_source("load_offsets", "test_scripts", fp)

dir(module)
```

On the first system, the output is correct:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'os', 'test_load_offsets']
```

I see one function called `test_load_offsets`, as expected.

On the second system, I get the following output:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'test_reset_position']
```

Note that I see a different function now: `test_reset_position`. However, on both systems, the file `test_scripts/load_offsets.py` is identical! More importantly, there is no function `test_reset_position` in this file.

There is, however, a function `test_reset_position` in a different file, namely `test_scripts/reset_position.py`. In addition, in the directory where I executed the code sample, there is a file `test_scriptsc` (this is the case on both systems). It contains, I think, byte code, but on the system where I see the problem I can recognise parts of the file `test_scripts/test_reset_position.py` in it. If I remove `test_scriptsc`, it works fine again, until load a different file and then the problem starts again.

So, my conclusion is that on the system with the problem, the file `test_scriptsc` is not updated correctly. However, I do not understand why, nor do I understand why the problem is only on one of the two systems. The only difference I can find between the two systems is that the problematic system runs Python Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu Linux 16.04.1 while the system without the problem runs Python 2.7.11+ on Ubuntu 16.04.

Can someone help me find out what is going on here? I have no clue what to look for...

Comment: What do you get if you look at the value of `module.__file__` on the two systems?

Comment: For both system `module.__file__` is `test_scriptsc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is failing is because I'm doing it wrong. The second argument to `load_source` should be the full path to the source file, not just to the directory containing it [Python 2.7.12 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_source).
I'm not sure why I came up with my implementation, nor do I know why Python 2.7.11 was accepting it anyway, but the solution is to do it the right way:

```
with open("test_scripts/load_offsets.py") as fp:
    m = imp.load_module("load_offsets", fp, "test_scripts/load_offsets.py", ("py","r",imp.PY_SOURCE))

dir(m)
```

This correctly gives:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'os', 'test_load_offsets']
```

I think the file `test_scriptsc` was an attempt of byte compiling a `.py` file, but since I didn't give the full path, I ended up with something that was a sort-of-compiled directory. Apparently Python 2.7.11 handled this differently than Python 2.7.12.